# How to use actions/checkout@master to get sources into specified folder?

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I'm trying to implement some automation tools in my github repository, but there are some problems I'm facing to. For now, I can't understand how to get sources into the specified folder.

For example, I have 2 branches

- the first one is the sources branch
- the second one is the test branch

Now I'm trying to clone the first branch, build the project (the project is in C++) and then clone the second one and build the second one and run the tests.

Can I do the stuff using actions/checkout or I have to use another approach?

Also if you have some understanding of how the actions/checkout action is implemented, please let me know. I'm very interested.

Comment: First things first, in Git world, you clone a `project` not a specific `branch`. I think you mean checking out to switch branches (`git checkout`). And secondly, what you mean by "actions"? GitHub workflow actions (https://github.com/features/actions) ? And it's not clear what is your question/problem.

Comment: @Eray No I mean exactly about cloning the branch, not the repository. Secondly - yes, I meant the github workflow actions.

Comment: You can not clone a branch. Cloning pulls all Git references (including branches) from remote to local. So, when you clone your repository, actually you fetch all branches. I don't have experience with GitHub Workflow Actions so let's wait for someone else's answer.

Comment: Why would you have tests in a separate branch?

Comment: @localheinz I don't really know. I thought that keeping them in separate branch is a better idea than keeping them together. Because if a user wants to download my provided software he/she doesn't really have to get the tests as well. Correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: You can use `.gitattributes` for that. See for example https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/33579.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use "path" parameters. See "Checkout multiple repos" in https://github.com/actions/checkout